# cmake multi-configuration project variables

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I wish to set a cmake variable to a certain value for debug configuration, and to another value for release. This works well with CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE conditional and single configuration projects, but I don't know how to do it in a multi configuration one, e.g. Visual Studio. Any ideas?

Comment: This depends a lot on what you want to achieve with this variable. Can you be more specific?

Comment: This variable will hold the location of a dependency which is different for both configurations.

Comment: So in principle a library that you are going to link against?

Comment: Yes, exactly - the library resides in a well defined location for every configuration.

Comment: Ok. I saw you ansered it, your solution is what I would have suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found you can get away with using both debug and release versions in a single variable:

```
set(VARIABLE debug debug.lib optimized release.lib)
```